# New difficulty scraping data with python requests from an asp.net form on a webpage (.aspx)

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping

I'm back with a problem concerning the previous answer to a similar question answered by @SIM.
[Difficulty scraping data with python requests from an asp.net form on a webpage (.aspx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786123/difficulty-scraping-data-with-python-requests-from-an-asp-net-form-on-a-webpage/66770295#66770295)

The following code was derived from his answer to go to a form at https://ndber.seai.ie/Pass/assessors/search.aspx, to retrieve the hidden captcha value and then submit the form. The result from the form submission is a multi-page table and each page of results is written to a .csv file.

It stopped working a while ago and I have been unable to find the problem. The hidden captcha is still being retrieved but the result from the post is always the initial page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import datetime


link = 'https://ndber.seai.ie/Pass/assessors/search.aspx'

LocalLog = open("SEAI_BER.log", "a")
LocalLog.write("Initial write to the file\n")

payload = {
    'ctl00$DefaultContent$AssessorSearch$dfSearch$Name': '',
    'ctl00$DefaultContent$AssessorSearch$dfSearch$CompanyName': '',
    'ctl00$DefaultContent$AssessorSearch$dfSearch$County': '',
    'ctl00$DefaultContent$AssessorSearch$dfSearch$searchType': 'rbnDomestic',
    'ctl00$DefaultContent$AssessorSearch$dfSearch$Bottomsearch': 'Search'
}

page = 1

def get_captcha_value():
    with HTMLSession() as session:
        LocalLog.write("\nGot into get_captcha_value \n")
        r = session.get(link)
        r.html.render(sleep=5)
        captcha_value = r.html.find("input[name$='ctl00$DefaultContent$AssessorSearch$captcha']",first=True).attrs['value']
        LocalLog.write(captcha_value)
        LocalLog.write("\nGot out of get_captcha_value \n")
        return captcha_value

with requests.Session() as s:
    row = 0
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (WindowMozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36'
    LocalLog.write("Got to requests.Session() \n")
    r = s.get(link)
    LocalLog.write("Writing the raw text content\n")
    # LocalLog.write(r.text)
#    LocalLog.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    payload['__VIEWSTATE'] = soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATE")['value']
    payload['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'] = soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")['value']
    payload['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = soup.select_one("#__EVENTVALIDATION")['value']
    payload['ctl00$forgeryToken'] = soup.select_one("#ctl00_forgeryToken")['value']
    payload['ctl00$DefaultContent$AssessorSearch$captcha'] = get_captcha_value()
    with open("../location.." + datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d") + "_SEAI_BER.csv", "w") as f:
        f.write("\"Name\",\"Company\",\"Address\",\"County\",\"Provinces\",\"E-mail\",\"Phone\",\"Website\"\n")
        while True:
            LocalLog.write("Writing the payload\n")
            for key, value in payload.items():
                LocalLog.write(f"{key}: {value}")
                LocalLog.write("\n")
            LocalLog.write("\n")
            res = s.post(link,data=payload)
            LocalLog.write(res.text)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
            if not soup.select_one("table[id$='gridAssessors_gridview'] tr[class$='RowStyle']"): 
                LocalLog.write("Hit the break on if not soup.select_one")
                break
            for items in soup.select("table[id$='gridAssessors_gridview'] tr[class$='RowStyle']"):
                csv_ready = ""
                for eachspan in items.find_all('span'):
                    if(len(eachspan.contents) > 0):
                        csv_ready = csv_ready + "\"" + eachspan.contents[0] + "\""
# This is where we write to a csv file
                f.write(csv_ready.replace("\"\"","\",\"") + "\n")
# Let's write to the BER_assessors table as well
            page+=1
            payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
            payload.pop('ctl00$DefaultContent$AssessorSearch$dfSearchAgain$Feedback')
            payload.pop('ctl00$DefaultContent$AssessorSearch$dfSearchAgain$Search')
            payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'ctl00$DefaultContent$AssessorSearch$gridAssessors$grid_pager'
            payload['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = f'1${page}'
```

If someone has an idea, I would greatly appreciate help in this.